# sql query doesn't select the right value's I need

Tags: sql, heidisql

I'm trying to only select the data with numbers in them (the table looks like this):

```
eteee 231
wrgrr
test 1
bioo 21
wee
```

with the query: `SELECT address1 FROM ps_address WHERE address1 not like '%[^0-9]%';`

but i get all the values right back.

Comment: `WHERE address1 like '%[0-9]%';`?

Comment: Is "eteee 231" a single record or two separate records?

Comment: eteee 231 is a single record

Comment: @jarlh's comment does what you need I'm not sure why you had a 'not like' when you wanted a like with the numeric check.

Comment: when i try it with like and not with 'not like'  I got no return at all

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ("HeidiSQL is a useful and reliable tool designed for web developers using the popular _MySQL_ server, _Microsoft SQL_ databases and _PostgreSQL_."...)

Comment: yes I'm using heidisql

Comment: And heidisql is connected to?

Comment: to the webshop ?

Comment: And the webshop database server is one of "_MySQL server, Microsoft SQL databases and PostgreSQL_" - which one?

Comment: that is a mysql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT address1 FROM ps_address WHERE address1 REGEXP '[[:digit:]]';
```

This returns the rows containing digits anywhere inside `address1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply write:

```
SELECT address1 FROM ps_address WHERE address1 like '%[0-9]%';
```

Comment: when i try that query I get no return what so ever

Comment: Are you sure the column's name is address1?

Comment: Remember, my query does not include " ^ " as your original one.

Answer (score 0):

this will work :

```
SELECT address1 FROM ps_address WHERE regexp_like(address1,'.*[0-9]+.*');
```

Comment: When i try that query I get the error that the regexp_like function doesn't exicst

Comment: its all working in my db i dont know what is heideisql but for orcale i
ts working